# Unable To Bring Online Any Database On A Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2016, alter

Over the weekend my Dev server experienced a very interesting issue. I have a scripts that periodically take several databases offline, and then bring them back online again. They ran, and took all the specified databases offline, but then failed to bring them online again, the specified error message was:

> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 7, Line 4 User does not have permission to
>   alter database 'XXX', the database does not exist, or the database is
>   not in a state that allows access checks. Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 4 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

This doesn't seem right to me as they we're run from a user account that has the following properties set:

[image]

I further validated that it wasn't a permissions issue by logging on to that server, running SSMS as an Administrator and logging in with my windows credentials (also a admin account) and executing the following SQL on the offline database:

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [XXX] SET ONLINE
GO
```

With the same results...

I've looked at the SQL logs for more details about the specific error, however there are no entries associated with this issue. I can reproduce this issue on every database on this particular server. The only way I've been able to get the databases online is by de-attaching and reattaching them.

Most other stack overflow tickets involving this error message are specific to one database or a specific user account. My issue spans all databases and all admin users I've tried so far, also my issue occurred on a script that had previous worked fine on this server and account, clearly something has shifted over the weekend that is causing this query to now fail. I wonder if anyone else has experienced this issue before?

## Update 1

[This post](http://www.developerscloset.com/?p=862) talks about how file security can trigger this error message, I granted full access to the user group on one of the databases, then reran the online command, no luck. My SQL Server service is running under a service account that is part of the "Administrator" user group and has full access to all database files.

## Update 2

All sorts of interesting idea's [put forward here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189274/113501), [also discussed here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-recover-suspect-database). Lots of commands and ideas on how to repair damaged databases with a several combinations of repair like SQL command, unfortunately none of them work in my situation, they either won't run on offline databases, or after detach and reattachment do not report any errors. Of course, there are always a number of posts simply insisting that the solution is permission based and that running: GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE will resolve all issues. For my admin user account it shouldn't make a difference, but it's a moot point as I can't even run that command on a offline database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tracked down the issue, apparently we had a completely unrelated SQL database instance on the same server in recovery mode. While it was recovering we we're unable to bring any offline instances online. Detach/re-attach would work, and we could restore the database just fine, but just not set it online.

The separate database finished recovering and we are now able to run the command without issue. I suppose in the future, if I don't care about the database that's in recovery(which I often don't) I'll following [the linked steps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/how-do-you-stop-take-offline-and-delete-a-sql-server-database-in-recovery/11176) to get rid of it, before restarting SQL Server and proceeding:

> Stop SQL Server
>
> Delete MDF + LDF
>
> Start SQL Server
>
> Restore (may need to drop first, comes up suspect)